# How to remove images in grid while exporting to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid with some data, for one column i have added image to better visibility to user.  now i have a export option to export grid to excel sheet. in excel i am getting image not found icon . i dont want to show the image to user in excel sheet. any help

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "123.xls"));
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
// gdAclog.AllowPaging = false;
// gdAclog.DataBind();
//Change the Header Row back to white color
gdAclog.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
//Applying stlye to gridview header cells
for (int i = 0; i < gdAclog.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    gdAclog.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1");
}
int j = 1;
//This loop is used to apply stlye to cells based on particular row
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gdAclog.Rows)
{
    gvrow.BackColor = Color.White;
    if (j <= gdAclog.Rows.Count)
    {
        if (j % 2 != 0)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
            {
                gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
            }
        }
    }
    j++;
}
gdAclog.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Which cell is your image in ?

Comment: image at  5 item template

Answer (score 2):

If you anyway don't want to show it, you might loop through all your cells and check if the content of the cell is a picture. `if(Table.Cell(row,col).GetType().Equals("msoPicture"))` then you set the content of the cell to null or any value you want to. For the picture, in case you still need it, you might save it in a temporary file or copy to clipboard(bad pratice).